# synology drive client connection failed please check your network settings

Tags: networking, nas, synology

I have a **Synology Nas DS1019+** and I have access to the admin panel.

I want to use **Synology Drive Client** but It cannot connect and shows the error below :

[image]

I had read from [Synology Knowledge Center](https://kb.synology.com/en-id/DSM/tutorial/DSM_update_why_connection_failed)

- Changing Proxy to Auto-detect didn't help me.
- Changing DNS didn't help me.
- Synchronize with NTP server didn't help me.
- *nslookup google.com* works fine
- 8.8.8.8 ping from your synology is OK

  ....

I believe that the network is fine but there is something with Synology...

Comment: Anyway, the message says to check your network settings. You want some help with that, but you don't provide any information about them. What is the path to the Internet? What does `netstat -rn` on the synology give? And does 8.8.8.8 ping from your synology? Does `nslookup google.com` on the synology work? Add the information to your question (not  as comment)